# Data Flow Flatten JSON Files Without Using Projections

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am looking to use a single Data Flow, that takes:

1. JSON File DataSet
2. Flattens Data
3. Adds a few standard dervied columns
4. Outputs to Parquet

Now my Dataset is parameterized bsaed on the type of Report.
I.e. 50 different reports (all different schemas), but because the pattern of what I am trying to do is exactly the same, can I do this without creating 50 different data flows and just use 1 data flow.

For example, all those 50 Reports do have the following in common:

1. It contains an JSON array which looks like this:
   [{"Report_Entry":[{"Column1":"Col1Value","Column2":"sdfldsfksd","Column3":"1afdssad"}, {"Column1":"sdfsf","Column2":"sdfdsff","Column3":"sdfdsf"}]}]

When I attempt to read the source in data flow, I see the Report_Entry and the array in the data preview.... but when I attempt to add the Flatten componenet (even by pattern matching, I can't seem to get it to unroll by Report_Entry) unless I add in the Projection.

Any ideas of how this can be acheived. Alternative is 50 different data flows each with its own projection, which can still work, but is slightly more painful to manage since its all repetitive.

See the above details for the steps I have tried.

Comment: Does all 50 reports have same schema? That is , whether all report has to be flattened basis the `Report_entry` field?

Answer (score 0):

When using [flatten transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) you need to import the projection or get the schema of file to pass the array in flatten transformation to unroll it.

Without importing projection, it is not able to recognize the array column. from the incoming stream and it will not be able to proceed further. To do this you need to provide the schema by importing projection also you will not be able to publish your pipeline without providing unroll by column to flatten transformation.

[image]

The only alternative is that only you need to create different data flow for different schema Json